# Declaring variable and assignment

Tags: java, class, variable-assignment, variable-declaration

I was just practicing java program in eclispe following is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
class Problem7
{
    public static void main(String args[]){
int num,sum=0,mod_num,count;//Syntax error on token ";", { expected after           
                             //this token. Ques=Why?
System.out.println("Enter a 5 digit number");
try(Scanner n1 = new Scanner(System.in))
{
    num = n1.nextInt();
}
for(count = 0; count <= 4; count=count+1)
{
        mod_num = num%10;
        num=num/10;
        sum = sum+mod_num;
}
System.out.println("The sum off digits is "+sum);
}
}
```

==========================================================================
The above code runs correctly without any error. However if i wanted to use a different class as "class sum_of_digits" with the following code. It starts to shows error in class "sum_of_digits" itself before i even create object.Following is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
class sum_of_digits
{
int num,sum=0,mod_num,count;//Syntax error on token ";", { expected after           
                             //this token. Ques=Why?
for(count = 0; count <= 4; count=count+1)
{
        mod_num = this.num%10;
        this.num=this.num/10;
        sum = sum+mod_num;
}
System.out.println("The sum off digits is "+sum);
}
```

======================================================================
However if i include the for loop in a method and make a necessary arrangements, then the code works fine, it runs without error and i get the desired result: Below is the new code with class "sum_of_digits":

```
import java.util.*;
class sum_of_digits
{
int num,sum=0,mod_num,count;//Syntax error on token ";", { expected after   
                            //this token
void loop()
{
    for(count = 0; count <= 4; count=count+1)
    {
        mod_num = this.num%10;
        this.num=this.num/10;
        sum = sum+mod_num;
    }
    System.out.println("The sum off digits is "+sum);
}
}

class Problem7 
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    sum_of_digits digit = new sum_of_digits();
    System.out.println("Enter a 5 digit number");
    try(Scanner n1 = new Scanner(System.in))
    {
        digit.num = n1.nextInt();
    }
    digit.loop();
}
}
```

My question is why cant i declare the for loop directly in class "sum_of_digits"?

Comment: Syntax errors are off topic here.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: I m pretty sure my question is not related to syntax and the dude below, did tell me the answer. So please look at it because it wasn't a syntax error. So thanks

Comment: The "dude" below pointed out that it is a syntax error.

Comment: But i haven't seen that anywhere, neither anybody told me its not correct way to do it. So i though it that way, but thanks for reminding me, i will make sure to try all variation

Comment: @BoristheSpider: But then how come under main it works and not here?

Comment: Because it is not allowed by the syntax.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Got it , there is no way to actually access the for loop in the class "sum_of_digits" right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a for loop in the class body. It's not allowed here.

```
class sum_of_digits
{
    int num, sum=0, mod_num, count;

    for(count = 0; count <= 4; count=count+1)
    {

    }
}
```

Executable statements like this need to be in a method, constructor, or initializer block.

```
class sum_of_digits
{
    int num, sum=0, mod_num, count;

    void loop() {
        for(count = 0; count <= 4; count=count+1)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Radopdef: huh, that didnt come to my mind. Thanks its working now.